# How can I sum a series of tabs across tabs?

Tags: microsoft-excel-2007, worksheet-function

I have an excel 2007 file with 13 tabs (a summary and one for each month), and want to produce a sum up across the same cell for each month in the summary sheet.

I have tried @sum(sheet2!a10:sheet13!a10) but produced an error.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What you want is a 3D formula like this:

```
sum(sheet2:sheet13!a10)
```